# Golden and Silver ratios, how about the roots of $x^2+x-1=0$?

Tags: ratio, golden-ratio

The golden and silver ratios are the roots of the equation $x^2-x-1=0$:
$$\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$ 
They show up in the formula of Fibonacci numbers:
$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$

Are the roots of the equation $x^2+x-1=0$ any significant and do they have some special names:
$$\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}?$$

Comment: The silver ratio is $1+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Changing the equation from $x^2-x-1=0$ to $x^2+x-1=0$ just changes the signs of the two roots, so they don't need much of a separate naming from the golden ratio.  One just needs a bit of care in explaining an application of them.

Comment: @Raskolnikov, in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931741/about-the-golden-ratio-conjugate) it was called that way.

Comment: The ratio can not be negative though. So, I assume the term "silver" for $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: For $x^2 + x - 1 = 0$, there is nothing really significant or noteworthy about the roots, other than one of them is $-\phi = \dfrac {-1-{\sqrt 5}}{2}$ or $-1.618$, and the other is $\dfrac {1}{\phi} = \dfrac {-1+{\sqrt 5}}{2}$ or $0.618$.

Comment: Ok, the terminology needs to be fixed. How about the main question: is it significant and does it have any name or is it applied in any known problem?

Comment: Whoops.  I've changed the answer...the short explanation is that there's nothing significant other than sign.